# ADS1015 max Sample

Tags: arduino, i2c, sample, rms

I bought an ADS1015 to perform measurements at the maximum frequency (3.3 kSPS) but from the tests I cannot exceed 500 samples. Modifying the library I saw that the set frequency is the maximum. how can I do?

```c
#include <Adafruit_ADS1X15.h>
Adafruit_ADS1015 ads;     /* Use this for the 12-bit version */
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  if (!ads.begin()) {
    Serial.println("Failed to initialize ADS.");
    while (1);
  }
}
void loop(void){
  Serial.println(ads.readADC_Differential_0_1());
}
```

Comment: By default the library set the sample rate at 1600, see the [source code](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_ADS1X15/blob/master/Adafruit_ADS1X15.cpp#L41), it can be changed by calling [setDataRate()](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_ADS1X15/blob/master/Adafruit_ADS1X15.cpp#L95) function with a value of [RATE_ADS1015_3300SPS](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_ADS1X15/blob/master/Adafruit_ADS1X15.h#L125).

Comment: Thanks for your help but I made this change on the library and my arduino always get 500 samples per second more or less

Comment: Your limitation might be caused by the much slower `Serial.print()`, nothing to do with the chip sampling.